# Difference between get_attribute and get in Selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was doing web **scraping**, when I came across the aforementioned are performing almost the same work. I'm sure there are differences, but I cannot understand.

Example of `get_attribute(),`

```
channel=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main-link"]') #Accessing the link of the channel
url=channel.get_attribute('href')
print(url)
```

Example of **get()**

```
urls=[]

for i in listOfLinks:
    u=i.get('href')

    try:
        urls.append('https://www.youtube.com'+u) #Since the fetched urls are not complete we need to append -https://www.youtube.com in front to fetch the complete url
    except:
        continue

print(urls)
```

Answer (score 0):

See `get()` is to open or launch any web URL in Selenium Python.

where as

`get_attribute` is to get the **attribute** of a **tag**. (which you generally see in HTML).

In your example, `//*[@id="main-link"]` this must represent a web element, right ? You may have seen as well this on UI. so here `id` is an attribute, same way `'href'` is an attribute.

so basically, this line means

```
url = channel.get_attribute('href')
```

for web element `channel` which is associated with `//*[@id="main-link"]` xpath, grab the `href` attribute.

Comment: Yes, but in the above example of `get()` ,I'm using the same to grab the `href` via `i.get('href')`. They are doing the same function here, right?

Comment: What is `i` , I  need to know ?

Comment: `i` is the loop control variable for the list of links' tags (scrapping video links from YouTube).
`pg = browser.page_source 
soup = BeautifulSoup(pg, 'lxml')
listOfLinks = soup.findAll('a',{'id': 'thumbnail'}) #Getting all the videos`

Comment: I don't see `i` in the above code that you have shared, but if `i` represent a web element, you can not do `i.get('')`, it has to be `i.get_attribute('')`